# Overview over all function objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a question which is more about a general understanding of loops and case-structures. Therefor I will not deliver a runable code.

Is there somehow an option to iterate over objects of a function? I use a if-elif differentiation to call diffent files of a dataset.

Is it possible for the user of this function to make a request about all possible cases the programmer/data base manager offers in this function?

I try to better explain my question in an example:

Example of available datasets given in a if-else-structure (the user might not be aware of all possible choices that can be called):

```
def data(date):
    if date == '20220318':
        file = 'dataset_a'
        return file
    elif date == '20220317':
        file = 'dataset_b'
        return file
    elif date == '20210712':
        file = 'dataset_c'
        return file
    elif date == '20210708':
        file = 'dataset_d'
        return file
    elif date == '20210621':
        file = 'dataset_e'
        return file      
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid date")
```

The result I am aiming at is a list of all "date"-objects like:

```
20220318
20220317
20210712
20210708
20210621
```

A direct iteration seems not to be possible like:

```
for date in data:
    print(date)
```

This leads to `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable.` Is there a way to call all possible choises?

Thanks for helping to understand how loops really work.

Comment: Given this function as is: no, there's no sane way to get all valid values for `date` from it. You need to store those values differently in a way that's accessible independently of the function, e.g. a dict: `dates = {'20220318': 'dataset_a', ...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to the question:

> "Is it possible for the user of this function to make a request about all possible cases the programmer/data base manager offers in this function?"

The answer is **yes**.  Below are listed two methods in particular, one 'messy' way, and another more robust way - but will require function re-factoring.

---

#### The messy way:

*(Please do not use this in production code)*

The advantage of this approach, is that you only require access to the function, and re-factoring is *not* required.

This approach uses the `inspect` module to parse the function into text. Then, a regex pattern is used to extract the possible `date` options, and returns these as a list.

```
import inspect
import re

# Define the regex pattern to extract the required values.
rexp = re.compile('date\s==\s\'(\d+)\'')
# Get source code in plain text.
src = inspect.getsource(data)
# Extract date strings.
dates = rexp.findall(src)
```

Output:

```
['20220318', '20220317', '20210712', '20210708', '20210621']
```

---

#### The more robust way:

This approach will require re-factoring the function, but will likely serve better in the long term. (recommended)

Simply place all possible dates and their associated file in a `dict`. Use the `dict.get()` method to return the requested value, or a default string if the requested value is not found.

The function also features a `return_dates_only` argument, which if passed as `True`, returns the keys to the `lookup` dictionary and provides the user with the valid options.

```
def data2(*, date: str=None, return_dates_only: bool=False):
    lookup = {'20220318': 'dataset_a',
              '20220317': 'dataset_b',
              '20210712': 'dataset_c',
              '20210708': 'dataset_d',
              '20210621': 'dataset_e'}
    if return_dates_only:
        return list(lookup.keys())
    else:
        return lookup.get(date, '[Error]: Invalid date')
```

Note: The asterisk in the function declaration tells the function to accept keyword arguments *only*.

Usage:

```
>>> data(date='20220318')
`dataset_a`

>>> data(date='20220101')
'[Error]: Invalid date'

>>> data()
'[Error]: Invalid date'

>>> data(return_dates_only=True)
['20220318', '20220317', '20210712', '20210708', '20210621']
```

---

#### Comments:

In answer to the question:

> "Can someone help me to understand why a concept like `for date in data ...` cannot work?"

Per the `__iter__` method's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__):

> This [an `__iter__ method`] is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the `for` and `in` statements.

... which the `data` function does not (nor can it) have.

Comment: Note that passing an empty string as a placeholder for `date` is fairly inelegant, that can be done better with optional/keyword arguments. Also note that if this is all this function does, you don't need it at all and can simply replace it with a dict.

Comment: And please don't ever do "the messy way"…

Comment: @deceze - Absolutely agreed. Updated to address. Thanks.

Comment: @s3dev thanks for the way. I could just add a dict as lookup for the request of all options and leave the rest as it is. Taht would work and the suggested code is working. Can someone help me to understand Python why a concept like `for date in data: [return] print(date)` cannot work? I still do not get the technical point behind it. Is it just not stored in memory?

Comment: @Swawa - My pleasure, thanks for the vote and accept. Interesting question.  The basic (short) answer is that the `data` *function* is not an iterable. Therefore is cannot be iterated. Think about the construct ... *if* the `data` function were an iterable, how would the `if` statement know exactly which object to extract and iterate? In other words, how would it know to pull out only the `date` variable (and its values) and not `elif` statement, for example?

Comment: ... for futher clarity, an iterable object or type must have an `__iter__` method in the class, which provides instruction to the caller (iterator) *what* should be iterated, and *how*. Simply put, the `data` function does not have this. However, you can build a class with an `__iter__` method, which can be constructed to act as an iterator.  However, in your case ... keep it simple and define a `dict`.  [Documentation reference](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the basics from these comments.

Comment: @s3dev Thanks a lot for giving a better understanding to me. As all values which the data variable can take are already defined in the function I naively thought that I can call and retrieve these lines. But you are right. Maybe it's a little bit comparable to Schrodingers cat thought experiment: In the function, only options are given, no 'real' objects defined, right? As long as these are 'only' options I can't do anything that choose one option that hints to a real dataset (or a real cat state)... Ok, now I understand pretty well better :-)